# Accessing "Ubuntu On Windows" through localhost

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

is there a way to do this? I've got it up and running but would love to build locally without use of wamp of some service like that.

What I would like to use the ubuntu subsystem for is a place to locally build websites/webapps locally before deployment. I have a server already that I use for a developer environment but would like to utilize this if possible..

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking for. What are you trying to build? What are you trying to access? What problem are you having? In general, if you have a Linux server process listening, you can connect to it just fine from Windows (and vise versa) using the Linux subsystem ("Ubuntu on Windows") of Win10.

Comment: updated OP with more info on what I am looking to do. 

Sorry I'm a total noob when it comes to this, I would assume that having the linux sybsystem running would mean that it is always running in the background. What I want to do is be able to open a browser and type `localhost` and it display the contents of my home dir just like I would access my remote server from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work just fine - networking between Win32 ("normal" Windows programs) and WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) works just like you'd expect it to, and a Win32 client (like a web browser) can connect to a WSL server / listener with no problem. Of course, both Win32 and WSL have to share the same set of ports, so if you have (for example) a Win32 app listening on port 8080, you won't also be able to have a WSL process listen on 8080 at the same time.

However, you make this (perfectly reasonable) assumption, which is unfortunately incorrect:

> I would assume that having the linux sybsystem running would mean that it is always running in the background.

For reasons which elude me (*the claim is "to conserve resources" but godammit, it's my computer, it can and should use as many resources as it needs to do the things I want it to do!*), Microsoft has decided that WSL will only operate while you have at least one `bash.exe` window open (`C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` being the Win32 program that launches and connects you to WSL's copy of `/bin/bash`). If you close all your `bash.exe` windows, WSL and all processes running within it, including daemons (background processes) will terminate. For more detail, see the [Windows Subsystem for Linux Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for "daemon".

So, you just have to leave a `bash.exe` window open while you connect to your Linux server (and you will have to have launched the server, since it'll get killed whenever you close all `bash.exe` windows including at reboots, etc.) and everything should work.

If you want to, you can even install an X11 server (there are free Win32 ones), run that and set WSL to use it as the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and then install and run graphical Linux apps (Firefox works tolerably well, if you don't need sound).

Comment: Thank you so much for your very thorough answer, I'll give the X11 server a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: ` If you want to, you can even install an X11 server (there are free Win32 ones), run that and set WSL to use it as the DISPLAY environment variable, and then install and run graphical Linux apps`

Fascinating! Good to know.